# Xcode 9.0.1 crash during uploading app to App Store

Tags: xcode, xattr

Xcode 9.0.1 (9A1004) crash after I updated Xcode during uploading,

In Terminal.app, When i run `xattr`

```
$ xattr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/xattr-2.7", line 7, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

How can i solve this problem

I tried

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade distribute 

easy_install distribute

sudo pip install -U pip
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py | python
```